# RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime, with correct timezone and settings

Tags: django, datetime

I am receiving this error message:

> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Z.data_zal received a naive datetime
> (2020-11-05 07:13:24) while time zone support is active.
> warnings.warn("DateTimeField %s received a naive datetime (%s)"

At this step of creating my models instance: `views.py`

```
 from django.utils import timezone

 t = Z(data_z=timezone.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), data_r=data_r, author=request.user)
 try:
     t.save()
```

So as far as I know this error occurs when using `datetime` module instead of `timezone`.
Sometimes the problem lies in wrong `settings.py` but I am running:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Warsaw'

USE_TZ = True
```

What seems to be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Don't .strftime() you make timezone.now() naive.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: How do I set datetime format then? I need to provide it to the model in this format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: no you don't... if your model field data_z  is models.DateTimeField() the timzone.now() will suffice